# Passing Bluetooth object to new activity

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm willing to make an app to send data over bluetooth. I have a main activity connecting to a bluetooth device and I can write data to the connected device. It works perfectly. I use the code sample of this repo :
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

I create a Bluetooth service "object" through this command :

```
mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getActivity(), mHandler);
```

and I can send data this way :

```
byte[] send = message.getBytes();
mChatService.write(send);
```

The problem is that, now, I want a new activity to start once my smartphone is connected to a bluetooth device and I want to pass the bluetooth chat object so the activity can get the object and, in its turn, write to the bluetooth device, like that :

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
newActivity.putExtra("BluetoothDevice", mChatService);
startActivity(JoystickActivity);
```

but obviously, this is not possible to pass my bluetooth object like that. I tried to look at Serializable type, but I didn't succeed to have something working.

Does somebody know how to pass this "BluetoothChatService" object to a new activity? Or maybe is there another way like making it accessible to all activities?